# How to setup a custom username and password to login to a website?

Tags: objective-c, json, url, ios6, passwords

I want to use my iOS app to login(2 UITextfields username/password) to a website(UIWebview). How would I go about doing this? Any suggestions and/or documents would be great.

Comment: What specific part of this do you need help with? Have you tried anything yet? Right now your question is far to broad and vague.

Comment: You need to send a HTTP request that contains the right username/password in the parameters (to know parameter names you should check the web page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can execute javascript in the UIWebView to autofill the username and password and submit the form

The code will be like the following

```
//autofill the form
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.formName.username.value = 'username'"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.formName.password.value = 'password'"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.formName.submit()"];
```

Note:
formName: is the form name
username: is the id of the username text
password: is the id of the password text

Comment: in the viewDidLoad for example, using outlet to the UIWebView

Comment: What do you mean by forName?

Comment: if you could send the html of the login page i'll explain exactly what do you need to do

Comment: the following code should work:      

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.new_user.user_login.value = 'username'"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.new_user.user_password.value = 'password'"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.new_user.submit()"];

Comment: My setup is that the login is a separate viewcontroller. I have an login viewController that I want to use a "sign in" button to goto the UIWebView that is on another ViewController.

Comment: i don't get your point? do you have a separate ViewController you use to get the username/password from the user? or what?

Comment: Yes, I have two separate ViewControllers. One is the username and password. The second one is for the UIWebView.

Comment: you can take the username/password from the first ViewController then user the code to set them in the UIViewController and submit the login form

Comment: I guess that is my question. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: I already posed a code for setting the username/password of the webview you just need to collect the username/password for your View Controller
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: [NSString stringWithformat:@"document.new_user.user_login.value = '%@'", username]]; [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: [NSString stringWithformat:@"document.new_user.user_password.value = '%@'", password]]; [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.new_user.submit()"];

Comment: So, I insert your original code into the uiwebview's viewdidload? Where would I insert the second bit of code within the login/password viewcontroller?

Comment: you can assign a delegate to the UIWebView and in the method "webViewDidFinishLoad:" you can add the code i posted in the comment above with the first refresh (i think at this point you have collected the username/password from user)